# 1:M relationship update field using formula?

Tags: visual-workflow, formula

I have a two custom objects `manager_object` and `employee_object` it has 1:M relationship, meaning one manager will have multiple employees.

My requirement is to pull the latest field from employee_object in the manager_object page layout.

How would you do that? the only one option I see is that use the flow to get latest based on the date and update the field in the manager_object and make that as a read-only.

But I see that has overhead in maintenance, is there a better way for this scenarios?

Comment: Please clarify: You want the **one** most recent ("latest") `employee_object`, or you want the value of some `latest` field from **each and every one** of the related `employee_object`s? (Or something else entirely?)

Comment: value of a field from the employee_object based on the latest date.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not fully grasping; so please confirm or correct this statement: You need to look at a "latest date" field on all related `employee_object` records, find the most recent one, then get a value from a different field on that one `employee_object`.

Comment: yes that's correct @Moonpie

Comment: Gotcha. I was originally thinking that you only needed the date of the most recent `employee_object`, which you could have done with a Roll-Up Summary field with a MAX on the `employee_object` "latest date" field. But since that is not the case, @sfdcfox has you covered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Flow or Apex Trigger is what you need here. Formulas can't refer to child objects or query child objects. If you need it only for UI purposes, though, you could write a component or Visualforce page to display the value on the page layout, or use a Report.

Comment: yes I thought so too but wanted to re-confirm.